# Error al guardar estado de Ansible Tower (AWX)

Tags: linux

Pues tengo un problemilla cuando he instalado AWX, todo bien hasta que cuando el host se reinicia, todo el contenido que tengo via web se pierde, todos los proyectos, credenciales, usuarios, etc. 
De alguna manera no guarda los cambios hechos y esto hace que cada vez que quiera realizar algo a través de un playbook, tenga que crearlo de 0 para probarlo.
¿Tenéis alguna idea de donde o de como se guarda la información de AWX?

PD: Tabajo con Ubuntu 18

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Me has ayudado 0

Comment: Puedes obtener la ayuda requerida en el sitio pero es importante tomes los consejos de @ElGerar, has realizado tres preguntas que necesitan una pequeña mejora, revisa [ask] para modificar tu pregunta y sea bien recibida en el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo encontré por mi mismo, resulta que cuando instalas Ansible, todo el progreso lo guarda en una carpeta temporal, más concretamente /tmp/postgress, la cosa es quitarle esa ruta y ya funciona de lujo.